# Whether I am writing the correct test method in Unit Test?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, unit-testing

I am develeloping MVC application and writing the unit test.
I am confused about the coding pattern/process of unit test.
I am writing the unit test but I am not aware of , whether I am writing in proper way or not.

I am giving one example of the test case please check.

Basically, in test method I am writing the same code which I have written in  GetPartiesByEmployee() method and I am comparing the no. of records which return from the method and the records return from code blog in test method is that correct ?

Is that correct  ?

> [TestMethod]
>
> ```
>     public void Test_Get_Parties_By_Employee_Method()
>     {
>      
>         var actualResult = oPartyHelper.GetPartiesByEmployee(6);
>         Employee oEmployee = new Employee();
>         oEmployee = db.Employees.Find(6);
>         var roles = oEmployee.Roles.ToList();
>         List<Party> parties = new List<Party>();
>         foreach (Role item in roles)
>         {
>             var PartyCollection = from e in item.Parties.OrderBy(e => e.Name)
>                                   where (e.IsDeleted == false || e.IsDeleted == null)
>                                   select e;
>             parties.AddRange(PartyCollection.ToList());               
>         }
>         parties=parties.Distinct().OrderBy(p => p.Id).ToList();
>         var expectedCount = parties.Count();
>         var actualList = (List<Party>)actualResult;
>         var actualCount = actualList.Count;
>         Assert.AreEqual(expectedCount, actualCount, "All parties are not same");
>     }
> ```

Actual Method :

```
public List<Party> GetPartiesByEmployee(int employeeId)
        {
            Employee oEmployee = new Employee();
            oEmployee = db.Employees.Find(employeeId);
            var roles = oEmployee.Roles.ToList();
            List<Party> parties = new List<Party>();
            foreach (Role item in roles)
            {
                var PartyCollection = from e in item.Parties.OrderBy(e => e.Name)
                                      where (e.IsDeleted == false || e.IsDeleted == null)
                                      select e;

                parties.AddRange(PartyCollection.ToList());

            }
            
            return parties.Distinct().OrderBy(p=>p.Id).ToList();             
        }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, this is not how unit testing works.  You don't copy the same code into the test method, you test the actual object which has the code.  (Just copying the code would not only create odd and probably unhelpful tests, but it would duplicate *everything* in the system, which is unmaintainable.)

So let's say you have a method like this:

```
public int ActualMethod()
{
    var x = 0;
    var y = 1;
    return x + y;
}
```

You would **not** test that code by doing this:

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var x = 0;
    var y = 1;
    Assert.Equal(1, x + y);
}
```

You should instead have something like this:

```
[Test]
public void TestMethod()
{
    var testableObject = new SomeObject();
    var expectedResult = 1;
    var actualResult = testableObject.ActualMethod();
    Assert.Equal(expectedResult, actualResult);
}
```

(Which you can modify for readability as you see fit.  I was perhaps overly-explicit with the lines of code and variable names in that test method, just to demonstrate what's happening.)

The idea is that the unit tests load the *actual* module being tested, not copies of the lines of code.  Think of it from an encapsulation point of view for object-oriented design.  Nothing outside of those objects, *including the tests themselves*, should know anything about their internal implementations.  The tests are just interacting with the objects and validating that the results match what's expected.  The tests don't care how those objects internally achieve the results, only that the results meet expectations.

In general, unit tests follow three steps:

1. Arrange
2. Act
3. Assert

That is...

First, you arrange the objects for your test.  This might involve resetting some static data into a known state, instantiating an object (or grabbing it from a factory, etc.), setting some properties, etc.  Basically you're creating a known state from which a test will be run.

Second, you act upon that object.  You perform some action which should change the state of the system in some way.  Usually this is just calling a method on the object (or perhaps passing the object to a method somewhere else in some cases).  This is what you're testing.  That the code which changes the state of the system will change it from one known state to another expected resulting state.

Third, you assert the result of the test.  Since you created a known state in the first step, changed the state in the second step, now you observe the resulting state in the third step.

Comment: I was writing an answer just like this and then your's pop up. I couln't explain it better. Good answer!

Comment: Nice explanation , but I am still confused, means If I follow your guideline, and If I want to implement in my system, then lets say my method returns 1000 records...so I have to know my method return 1000 records and I have to right test method by considering method returns 1000 records ?

Comment: @user1650894: In that example, does the method _always_ return _exactly_ 1000 records?  And is the unit test in question just testing that fact?  If so, then you'd just call the method and compare the resulting count with the value 1000.  If, on the other hand, you don't know ahead of time what the count should be then the "Arrange" step was missed.  Unit tests need to be run in complete isolation with known data and known expected results.

Comment: Big No,  I don't know how much records it will return...then how come I know whether return count is correct or not ?

Comment: @user1650894: If you don't know what the result should be, then what are you testing?  That is, how can you know if the behavior of the system is "wrong" if you don't have a definition of "right"?  I still think the Arrange step is what you're missing in this case.  When you call `GetPartiesByEmployee()` you should be calling it on a known set of test data and nothing more.  And that test data should have a known number of parties for an employee.  If this test is using *live* (and *unknown*) data then it's not a unit test.

Comment: same thing I have ask in first comment, I have to know the how many records method is going to return in advance. isnt it ?

Comment: @user1650894: Yes, in an isolated test you should know in advance what the result of the test should be.  For a unit test which involves fetching records this is often accomplished by mocking the back-end database to always return an expected result.  If mocking is not an option and the test has to be an integration test (which means using an actual database in the described case) then the test would first reset the database into a known state (with known data) before executing the test.

Comment: so,summary is when I am going to write the method for fetching the records, then Im supposed to know the no. of records which will that method returns ?

Comment: @user1650894: Not generally when you write the method itself, but when you're testing the method you should, yes.  In order to test something, you need to have an expected result.  (Otherwise what are you testing it for?)

Answer (score 0):

You can use NUnit in several ways. It depends on your code and what your test is all about. In your case yes, comparing totals you would use the AreEqual method. Another common example is if you would like to see if a code generates exceptions or not - maybe to check library updates etc. Something similar to the following might be useful :

```
        [TestCase]
        public void TestCase()
        {
            try
            {
                // Write you code here that might generate an exception

                Assert.AreEqual(true, true);
            }
            catch (Exception e)
            {
                Assert.Fail(e.Message, e.GetType().Name);
            }
        }
```

As you can see if the executes successfully I use AreEqual, and comparing true with true so it will execute fine. If however the code generates an exception, I'd send back the error messages.

Comment: no, I am not looking for it...I have written a code block in method and same code block I have written in test cases...is that correct, is this the way that unit test get written ?